# How to convert an Akka Source to a scala.stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream, scala-streams

I already have a `Source[T]`, but I need to pass it to a function that requires a `Stream[T]`.

I could `.run` the source and materialize everything to a list and then do a `.toStream` on the result but that removes the lazy/stream aspect that I want to keep.

Is this the only way to accomplish this or am I missing something?

**EDIT**:

After reading Vladimir's comment, I believe I'm approaching my issue in the wrong way.  Here's a simple example of what I have and what I want to create:

```
// Given a start index, returns a list from startIndex to startIndex+10.  Stops at 50.
def getMoreData(startIndex: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[Int]] = {
  println(s"f running with $startIndex")
  val result: List[Int] = (startIndex until Math.min(startIndex + 10, 50)).toList
  Future.successful(result)
}
```

So `getMoreData` just emulates a service which returns data by the page to me.
My first goal it to create the following function:

```
def getStream(startIndex: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Stream[Future[List[Int]]]
```

where the next `Future[List[Int]]` element in the stream depends on the previous one, taking the last index read from the previous Future's value in the stream.  Eg with a startIndex of 0:

```
getStream(0)(0) would return Future[List[0 until 10]]
getStream(0)(1) would return Future[List[10 until 20]]
... etc
```

Once I have that function, I then want to create a 2nd function to further map it down to a simple `Stream[Int]`.  Eg:

```
def getFlattenedStream(stream: Stream[Future[List[Int]]]): Stream[Int]
```

Streams are beginning to feel like the wrong tool for the job and I should just write a simple loop instead.  I liked the idea of streams because the consumer can map/modify/consume the stream as they see fit without the producer needing to know about it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea. How do you think your `Stream` should behave when you want to get the next element from it and the materialized reactive stream cannot provide it (yet)? How errors should be handled? How the consumer of the `Stream` should close the materialized reactive stream when it is done with it? I think it is possible to answer these questions, but the resulting abstraction would be leaky and unwieldy.

Comment: Hmm, I'm new to both scala streams and akka streams, so maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way.  I created the `Source[T]` because I need to fetch that `T` from a url, which means I have a `Future[T]` instead.  I thought I'd use `mapAsync` to get around this issue.  I guess what I'm really after is converting a `Stream[Future[T]]` to a `Stream[T]`, only calling the url when it actually needs more.  Have I gone in the completely wrong direction?

Comment: Some code examples in the question couldn't hurt...

Answer (score 0):

Scala Streams are a fine way of accomplishing your task within `getStream`; here is a basic way to construct what you're looking for:

```
def getStream(startIndex : Int)
             (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Stream[Future[List[Int]]] = 
  Stream
    .from(startIndex, 10)
    .map(getMoreData)
```

Where things get tricky is with your `getFlattenedStream` function.  It is possible to eliminate the `Future` wrapper around your `List[Int]` values, but it will require an `Await.result` function call which is usually a mistake.

More often than not it is best to operate on the Futures and allow asynchronous operations to happen on their own.  If you analyze your ultimate requirement/goal it is usually not necessary to wait on a Future.

But, iff you absolutely must drop the Future then here is the code that can accomplish it:

```
val awaitDuration = 10 Seconds

def getFlattenedStream(stream: Stream[Future[List[Int]]]): Stream[Int] = 
  stream
    .map(f => Await.result(f, awaitDuration))
    .flatten
```

Comment: The gotcha part is that `.from(startIndex,10)` only works if we know ahead of time what the indexes will be.  However what I'm after is that the next index (10 in this case) must be determined by the result of the previous Future.  Each step in the stream must wait for the previous future to complete before it can be calculated.